# django-registration-redux and spurious migration from DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD of BigAutoField

Tags: django

I installed [django-registration-redux](https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) 2.11 into Django 4.1.6.

When I run `makemigrations`, it makes a migration to change an id field to `BigAutoField`:

```
# Generated by Django 4.1.6 on 2023-02-03 19:33

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ("registration", "0005_activation_key_sha256"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name="registrationprofile",
            name="id",
            field=models.BigAutoField(
                auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name="ID"
            ),
        ),
    ]
```

I suspect this is because DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD is now BigAutoField as of Django 3.2, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields).

However, it's creating a migration in my virtualenv, not under source code control:

```
$ ./manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'registration':
  .venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/registration/migrations/0006_alter_registrationprofile_id.py
    - Alter field id on registrationprofile
```

So that's not gonna work well.

I don't want to change my DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD to `AutoField`.  I just want to change it for django-registration-redux I guess?

I see that registration [already](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/blob/main/registration/models.py#L309) [has](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/issues/413) `default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.AutoField'`, so I'm puzzled as to why Django is making this migration.

I tried adding my own `registration/apps.py` into source code control with `default_auto_field` as `AutoField`, and that didn't work.

Suggestions?

I might just have to move to `django-allauth` or back to `django-registration`, [as they suggest](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/issues/182).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see that registration already has `default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.AutoField'`, so I'm puzzled as to why Django is making this migration.

The reason `default_auto_field` will likely not work is because it is defined on the *model*, not the app config.

> I tried adding my own `registration/apps.py` into source code control with `default_auto_field` as `AutoField`, and that didn't work.

This will work… on your `registration` app, so the models defined in that app, not in other apps.

Likely the best way to fix this is to fix it on the package itself, by specifying an `AppConfig` that then defines, for the scope of that package, the `default_auto_field`. I submitted a [pull request (#431) <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/pull/431) for this.